# Persistent Dataset for WPF Browser App?

Tags: c#, wpf, dataset, webbrowser-control

I am on a quest to find the best method to implement this data structure in my WPF c# .NET 4.0 web application.

**App Details:** This application will have many users at one time. I'm working with a database that has 2 tables linked together, both with <10k rows, but they will grow with time. One table will need to be checked for updates periodically.

**Question:**
I created a dataset to hold all information. My unit test shows it takes ~0.2 seconds to populate the dataset from the database. This is no time if the dataset will persist across the application. Can it persist across the application for many users?

The other method I can think of is using observable collections for the data and storing them in a singleton. Is there any method that I am missing here or something that will work better for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding some really important concepts here. First of all, WPF is not ASP.Net, WPF applications do not "run at server". WPF applications run at the computer that executes them (I.E the client) regardless of being an XBAP that runs inside Internet Explorer.

Therefore, you cannot have such thing as a "singleton" shared between many instances of your WPF application because each instance will be run on a separate computer on its own process. There's no practical way to share memory between these instances.

Then, if you need a "Web Application", WPF might not be suitable for your project. WPF is not a web technology, it is a rich desktop application technology that does not depend on the crappy implementations of HTML or anything like that.

Now, if you need (or desire) the richness and awesomeness and ease of development WPF provides, you will have to implement a Client/Server application, possibly using WCF or any other communications technology to enable your rich Client to communicate with the Server.

The "Server" will be an application responsible for querying the data from the database, then possibly caching it in memory, and then sending it to the client. Usually a WCF Service application is enough for this, although depending on your requirements you may need to implement more layers on top of it.

Beside this, I don't think there is a good reason to send a WPF client 10k rows of information, so you will have to come up with some paging mechanism in order to send the data in "chunks" instead.

Please provide more details about what you need and I can give you more insight.

Comment: That does clear up how WPF browser applications run. The main reason for choosing a WPF browser application is that my client is running IE7. The application has a tree view and each element in the tree can open a new tab when the user double clicks on it. I could find no easy tab solution that worked in IE7 the way it did in modern browsers (Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, etc), thus the 'WPF Browser Application' seemed the best approach. Thank you for the informative answer.